# What is the event referred to in this passage from Hermann von dem Busche's Vallum Humanitatis?

Tags: syntax, history

In Hermann von dem Busche's *Vallum Humanitatis*, a spirited defense of renaissance humanism against scholastics at the University of Cologne, I have come across a [puzzling passage](https://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/en/view/bsb00021286?page=20).

Ecce tibi, quam pulchre promovent bona studia, quamque recte curent honorem universitatis suae, qui fere sicut Ephesii neminem apud se frugi esse patiebantur, ita ipsi apud se neminem aut docere, aut discere eloquentiae studia permittunt. Sed si quis extiterit forte talis, dicunt, alio in loco, & apud alios sit ille.

Two marginal notes are attached. The first corresponds to the beginniing of the line:

Eia qualis isti promotoris studiorum

The second corresponds to *Ephesii*:

Ephesii publico edicto omnes frugi de sua civitate exire iusserunt

I have two questions about this passage.

First, what is happening grammatically in the first marginal note? The noun *promotor* is found in other, related works, so is this to be understood "isti [sunt] qualis promotoris studiorum"? It seems awkward.

Second, what is the expulsion of people from Ephesus referred to in the text and the second marginal note?

Comment: Seb & I have been chatting about the uses of "frugi" (below): how would you translate this in the second marginal note?

Comment: @tony frugi is a dative of purpose (in A&G terms) that originally meant something like "(good) for eating" and then was applied more broadly to mean "useful, serviceable, fit for some purpose." It is used like an adjective, but instead of declining to match the case of the head word, it always remains dative. homo frugi = good/useful/worthwhile person

Comment: @tony so I would translate something like "By public edict the Ephesians ordered all the worthwhile people to leave their city." Just as, according to Busche, the university is driving out the humanists, the truly educated men.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first marginal note seems to mean: "Hah, what advancers of studies these are!" It's an accusative (plural) of exclamation. As pointed out by TKR, the nominative *isti* cannot be squared with that, but I have no better explanation than that it should read *ipsos*.

The passage refers to the event that Strabo recounts in his [*Geography*, 14,1,25](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0239%3Abook%3D14%3Achapter%3D1%3Asection%3D25):

> Among illustrious persons in ancient times natives of Ephesus were Heracleitus, surnamed Scoteinus, or the Obscure, and Hermodorus, of whom Heracleitus himself says: “The Ephesians, youths and all, deserve hanging, for expelling Hermodorus, an honest citizen, a citizen distinguished for his virtues, and saying, let there be no such amongst us; if there be, let it be in another place and among other people.”

While obviously originally in Greek, a widely used Latin translation of the Geography was published by [Wilhelm Xylander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Xylander) in 1571. [He renders the passage thus](https://books.google.de/books?id=reCqf674GGMC&pg=PA739):

> Viri in ea memorabiles nati sunt, antiquis temporibus Heracleitus qui Scoteinus, id est tenebricosus fuit ob obscuritatem sermonis cognominatus. & Metrodorus, de quo sic Heracletus: Digni sunt Ephesii qui ad puerum usque omnes strangulentur, quod Hermodorum virum inter ipsos frugi eiecerunt, addito, Nemo nostrum frugi esto, aut alibi id esto & inter alios.

This translation is perhaps what Busche refers to.

Comment: If it's an accusative of exclamation, what do you make of the nominative *isti*?

Comment: @TKR Good point, I overlooked that, but my best guess would be that it is a misprint.

Comment: Eia does not call for an accusative of exclamation, so if it’s a misprint, I would be inclined to read it the other way: eia quales isti promotores studiorum. This accords nicely with the main text.

Comment: @Kingshorsey OK, but then you need to emend two words instead of one...

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Xylander wrote, "...addito, Nemo...", capital letter "N" after a comma? The dative, indeclinable adjective, "frugi" = "worthy"; "useful", written twice, line 5. The first one is translated to, "an honest citizen, a citizen distinguished for his virtues"--isn't that over-doing it? The second one seems to mean, "of such a kind that"; therefore, wouldn't "dignus est" have been better? On line 3, "Digni sunt" was used to describe the Ephesians. How would you translate "frugi" in Kinghorsey's second marginal note?

Comment: @tony please note that these are two completely independent translations (into English and Latin, respectively) of the same Greek original, which as far as I'm concerned is an impenetrable wall of squiggly curls. In fact, they may even be based on different versions of the original, who knows. What I can see is that the key Greek word here is ὀνήιστος. Messrs. Hamilton and Falconer said "honest," Xylander went with *frugi* (and not *honestus*), for which I would say "honest" or "virtuous."

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: In Kinghorsey's example I'm guessing that "frugi" = "worthy", in the sense of "deserving": the Ephesians expelled all those who deserved to be.

Comment: @tony No, I believe that is a misinterpretation. The Ephesians didn't suffer a goody-two-shoes gladly. They didn't want to live next to Ned Flanders. So they said: Oh, you're so frugi? Well, be frugi somewhere else.